# Tracking recently crashed applications

Tags: c#, crash-reports, crash

Is it possible to create a program that determines what applications have just recently crashed?

An example.

I open mozilla, and I open power point, but power point crashes.

Using a program, can I check what programs recently crashed?

Thanks in advance
-Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to examine the EventLog using the `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx

IIRC, you could filter Application Error events with id 1000 and evaluate the data.

I know, my answer is not a comprehensive walk-through, but hopefully a useful hint.